# CouchDb, Java: HTTP entity may not be null

Tags: java, couchdb

In my Java application Im trying to connect to couchDb on external server. I see error message connection timed out.

error msg:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet servlets.Chat
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **HTTP entity may not be null**
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:200)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:273)
```

My CouchDb properties

```
CouchDbProperties prop = new CouchDbProperties()
    .setDbName("lcouchdb")
    .setCreateDbIfNotExist(true)
    .setHost("chatapp.couchappy.com")
    .setPort(80)
    .setUsername("abc@gmail.com")
    .setPassword("bla blaaa")
    .setProtocol("http");
```

I have tried removing .setPort(80) again my app throws an error

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Port is invalid: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5984 is the default port for couchdb, but on Couchappy hosting, to improve security, only https on port 443 is allowed.

Plain http on port 80 or 5984 is potentially not safe and prone to man-in-the-middle attacks, so to fully prevent this, Couchappy staff decided to accept connections only on ssl on port 443.

443 is the default port used by browsers when using https. So this means that Couchappy users can hosts on it any kind of data, even a website and let their visitors and google index bots to access it to the url https://thedomainyouwant.couchappy.com instead of the ugly http://thedomainyouwant.couchappy.com:5984

Please note that, if you use some kind of java library, or something like that, you should explicitly set protocol "https" and port "443" instead of 5984.

Thanks for your questions, we are going to prepare a FAQ page on Couchappy website too.

Comment: The "HTTP entity may not be null" error will also occur if any of the host, port, username, or password details are incorrect when specifying the `CouchDbProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it times out because the server is not responding, not a code issue

```
curl -v http://chatapp.couchappy.com:5984/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f88c2804000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f88c2804000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to chatapp.couchappy.com port 5984 (#0)
*   Trying 62.149.192.34...
```

Comment: I have tried using this way, even from the browser it doesnt show anything

Comment: I realized that web address is sitting on port 80 and changed my props port to 80. Now I see the error HTTP entity may not be null

Answer (score 0):

in my case i got status code 204 with no entity
after reading the server api docs again i found out 204 is actually sign that
the server received the info and everything is ok.

cheers